# How to pass additional parameters to DialogFlow using Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, json, dialogflow-es

I am using the javascript SDK for DialogFlow and need to pass some additional parameters from my angular application.  The client.textRequest can take an options paramter which I attempted to use as follows:

$scope.options = {
            data: { 
                    userid : "testid",
                    client : "testclient"
                   }
        };

```
    var client = new ApiAi.ApiAiClient({accessToken: 'myapikey'});

    $scope.sendMessage = function() {
        return client.textRequest($scope.messageText, $scope.options).then((response) => {
            $scope.messages.push($scope.messageText);
            $scope.messages.push(response.result.fulfillment['speech'] || 'I can\'t seem to figure that out!');
                $scope.messageText = "";
            });

    }
```

https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/query#query_parameters_and_json_fields from the /query document i'm not 100% sure if data is the right parameter to use.  I saw another post about nodejs saying to add the data in the originalRequest parameter.  I'm not sure how this should function using the javascript sdk.